# Arithmetical hierarchy and complexity course note?

Tags: logic, computability

In my note, our professor talk about `Arithmetical hierarchy`. at the end he wrote all of these is True. My main problem is how these are True? ($N$ means Natural Numbers, and $W_e$   is the set of inputs for which the program encoded by $e$  halts)

> {$ x \in \mathbb{N}| W_x$ is recursive } $ \in \Sigma_3$
>
> {$ x \in \mathbb{N} | W_x$ =$N$ } $ \in \Pi_2$
>
> {$ x \in \mathbb{N} | \bar{W}_x$ is finite } $ \in \Sigma_3$

Thanks to any idea or hint.

Edit after 1 answer is received. infact when we want to solve this question via the proposed answer we get stuck when we ran into:

> {$ x \in \mathbb{N} | \phi_x$ is total and bounded} $\in \Pi_2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What are your own thoughts on the problem? Do you know what $\Sigma_3$ and $\Pi_2$ means?

Comment: @mrp, thanks so much. I read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy

Comment: @mrp, Is it possible to add some hints ? my professor teach us with just example not definition :)

Comment: I don't really know much about the arithmetical hierarchy myself, but it seems that what you need to do is translate the statements that characterise your sets into a statement in predicate logic. If the logic statement is of the form $\exists x \forall y \phi(x,y)$, then the set is $\Pi_2$, and if it is of the form $\forall x \exists y \forall z \phi(x,y,z)$, then it is $\Sigma_3$.

Comment: Wow, nice !, but another problem raises. can these statements translate into your logical form? @mrp.

Comment: What is N in the second set?

Comment: I correct it, Natural Numbers... @mrp.

Comment: These problems don't have anything *directly* to do with computer science or computational complexity. And, because they are written with the $\phi_x$ notation, they are neutral about which model of computation is used, so they are not directly related to Turing machines. I have adjusted the tags accordingly.

Comment: What are your own thoughts about the problems @LoveComplexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\varphi_x$ is total and bounded if and only if it satisfies the following two conditions:

(1) $\forall a\exists b (\varphi_x(a)[b]\downarrow)$ (**totality**; here . . . $[b]$ means "in $b$ steps"); and

(2) $\exists c\forall a(\varphi_x(a)<c)$ (**boundedness**).

Now (1) is $\Pi^0_2$, but (2) is $\Sigma^0_2$; so "total and bounded" = "(1) and (2)" is **not** obviously $\Pi^0_2$.

In fact, the statement is wrong - the right claim should be "total and **un**bounded is in $\Pi^0_2$" (and, in fact, is $\Pi^0_2$-complete).

---

Let's show that, in fact, $Y$="total and bounded" is **not** in $\Pi^0_2$. How would we do this?

Well, a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is $\Pi^0_2$ if and only if there is some computable total function $f(x, s)$ of two variables such that $$n\in A\iff\lim \sup_{s\rightarrow\infty} f(n, s)=\infty.$$ So suppose $f(x, s)$ is a computable total function; we'll find some $y$ such that $$y\in Y\iff\lim \sup_{s\rightarrow\infty} f(n, s)\not=\infty.$$  This will show that $Y$ is not $\Pi^0_2$.

This turns out to actually be rather easy: let $y$ be such that $\varphi_y(n)=f(y, n)$. (Exercise: how do we know that such a $y$ exists? This requires a theorem . . .) Then it's clear that $\varphi_y$ is total, so $y\in Y$ iff $\varphi_y$ is bounded.

BUT! $\varphi_y$ is bounded iff the function $s\mapsto f(y, s)$ is bounded, so we have $y\in Y\iff\lim\sup_{s\rightarrow\infty}f(y, s)\not=\infty$, so we are done.

Comment: BTW, "is $\Pi^0_2$-complete" is a strengthening of "is $\Pi^0_2$": $X$ is $\Pi^0_2$-complete if, not only is $X\in \Pi^0_2$, but it is *maximally $\Pi^0_2$*: any other $\Pi^0_2$ set is many-one reducible to $X$. $\Gamma$-completeness is defined similarly for other levels $\Gamma$ of the arithmetical hierarchy. It is an interesting phenomenon that almost every reasonably-defined set of natural numbers is complete with respect to its obvious level in the arithmetical hierarchy.

Comment: Perhaps you could mention that "total and bounded" is $\Pi^0_2 \land \Sigma^0_2$, and so it is $\Delta^0_3$.

Comment: Would you please complete your answer for all options ? to approve and set bounty.